# Breaking out of recursive function with keyListener?

Tags: java, function, recursion

I've tried installing some keylisteners in my view class to terminate this method. But it seems like the method wont stop. I'm unsure how to actually stop it from executing? The button seems to be pressed the whole time the method is executed.

```
 public void method1() {

    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        Compare.captureScreen(800, 550, 200, 50);
        if (Compare.processImage("image.png") == true) {
            robot.mouseMove(890, 576);
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        } else if (Compare.processImage("image.png") != true) {
            if (Compare.file.exists()) {
                Compare.file.delete();
            }
            robot.delay(2000);
            method1();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("method1");
    btnNewButton.setFocusable(true);
    btnNewButton.requestFocus();
    btnNewButton.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            theModel.method1();
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(163, 113, 101, 23);
    mainPanel.add(btnNewButton);
```

Comment: You're probably pressing and releasing the keys too quickly. I usually use `rob.setAutoDelay(150);` whenever I'm simulating GUI input. Without the auto delay, the `Robot` doesn't process the key release event. I wish I knew why. Perhaps someone could explain.

Comment: This comment is off-topic ... but it is a bad style to write expression like `expr == true` or `expr != true`.

Comment: @AustinD: it has nothing to do with that. He's tying up the Swing event thread with long-running code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so then it's the fact that he's using `robot.delay(2000)`?

Comment: @AustinD: yes, He could use a Swing Timer for this as well, and that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling long-running code on the Swing event dispatch thread (EDT), completely tying up the thread and making Swing unresponsive. The solution here is to have your long-running code run **off** the EDT and in a background thread.

Comment: @AndersLassen: Please have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). It will tell you all about the EDT, and how tying it up can freeze the GUI. You can create and use any thread to get the code off of the event thread, but perhaps a better solution is to use a SwingWorker, something that the tutorial linked to above will tell in detail.

Comment: Thanks, ill try that.